# Pass parameter to a method and read the return value?

Tags: c#, roslyn

Having this code:

```
var code = "public class TestClass {" +
           "  public int HelloWorld(int num) {" +
           "    return 5 + num;" +
           "  }" +
           "}";

var script = CSharpScript.Create(code);
var x = (await script.RunAsync()).ReturnValue;
```

How does one pass a value for the parameter, call the method and read the return value?

Comment: You need to get the type compiled by the script, then use Reflection.  I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples#parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continue with another code is the simplest.

```
var call = await script.ContinueWith<int>("new TestClass().HelloWorld(3)").RunAsync();
var x = call.ReturnValue;
```

---

By the way, `CSharpScript` is a scripting engine which does not require you having class and method like ordinary C# program. You can just use `5 + num` as script content.

```
var code = "5 + num";
var numValue = 3;

var setParam = await CSharpScript.RunAsync("var num = " + numValue + ";");
var runCode = await setParam.ContinueWithAsync(code);
var x = runCode.ReturnValue;
```

For full example, take a look of [RoslynScript/Script.cs](https://github.com/tommyinb/RoslynScript/blob/master/RoslynScript/Script.cs)